# Rails plugin to convert an email address to image to protect from harvesting?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I need to display the email address of users on their profile page on my site. I don't want to show the email in text to protect from harvesting. I'm looking for a rails plugin of some sort for converting the email address (stored in DB) into a image, and then displaying on the profile page. Does anyone know of any such plugins?
Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but if the site is public, you should never be showing an email address on a profile page.  Imageized or not, it's probably divulging too much about your user.

Comment: the user actually wants to show his/her email address for connected people to contact him/her.

Comment: Yeah I can see *why* they would want to show it.  But if the person is connected (by which I mean personA allows personB), then why protect it at all?  If you are not person b, then don't show it.  If you are worried about search engines picking it, they'd have to be crawling as a connected user.  Maybe I don't know enough about the requirement, but best practices would seem to tend to lean toward the fill out a form and send that to the user (esp. if personB is not connected to personA).

Comment: Don't forget the many people can't see very well so converting text to an image gives you an accessibility problem, if a screen reader can figure out your image then so can a harvesting bot. You're trying to solve the wrong problem and that will only lead to other problems.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use imagemagick ( http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#text_operators ) to do it you can do something like this:

```
convert -background lightblue  -fill blue -pointsize 16 -size 120x caption:'foo@bar.com' email.gif
```

(this would create an image named email.gif with the email foo@bar.com  you would want to play with your -background and -fill colors to get it to match the look and feel of your site.

this is probably also possible to do more programmatically with something like mini_magick ( https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick ) or rmagick ( http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/ ) underneath the surface they both take advantage of imagemagick.

Having said all that, if the goal is to simply protect against emails being crawlable, I would just have javascript paint the email addresses on window.load.  you could serve them in an encoded format, hidden from the dom, and then when the window loads javascript can read this data and inject it as html into the appropriate place in your dom.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the instructions for integrating [mailhide](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/) from the recaptcha folks

**Added** I looked at my code and saw that, in fact, I use `mail_hide` from the ruby [recaptcha gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-recaptcha)

**ps** I use "opt in" for my users--their email only appears (via the recaptcha) if they want it to be public.